# Does laravel db rollback work for the opened transaction only?

Tags: laravel

I have a question regarding the `DB::rollback()` and `DB::transactions` methods. So first of all to understand the context of my questions I have the following transaction:

```
$reponse = DB::transaction(function() use ($request) {
    try {
        ...
        ...
        ...

        if (sizeof($this->headersErrors) > 0) {
            throw new Exception(json_encode($this->headersErrors));
        }

        $exploedZip = explode("/",$multimediaFilePath);
        $multimediaFolder = explode(".zip",$exploedZip[sizeof($exploedZip)-1]);


        $this->importContent($routesFilePath, "Routes","temp/multimedia/".$timeTrimed."/".$multimediaFolder[0]);
        //This is the part I'm asking about
        if (sizeof($this->contentErrors) > 0) {
            throw new Exception(json_encode($this->contentErrors));
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        return response()->json([
            "errors" => $e->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
});
return $reponse;
```

As you can notice, I'm doing some work inside the `try` bloc and when I catch an exception I rollback the transaction. However, what I'm concerned of, is how I'm doing it.

For simplicity, the `importContent` method does two things, validate if there are any errors, and then insert the data given. The first part is what bothers me, if the validation fails, meaning there are errors in the data, I don't insert anything (I'm using a loop with a `continue` before insertion once an error is found).

**So my main question here, is in this exact scenario where validation fails and no data inserted, what would the `DB::rollback()` method do since there were no transactions made to begin with. Would it do it nothing, or would it rollback another transaction I didn't make?**